# JS functions not working after DOM modifications with Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a modal where content is loaded by an Ajax call.

The Ajax call loads a new form into the modal body, and I need to use some js plugins on this form (display a map,  use TinyMCE, Chosen.js, etc.)

I tried a lot of things I've read in other posts but none are working for me...

```
// Performs a lot of things
function init() {
    $('.chosen').chosen();
    $('.toggleswitch').bootstrapToggle();
    tinymce.init();
}

// Long Google Maps function
function initAutocomplete() {
    // a lot of code
}

// Another Google Maps function
function fillInAddress() {
    // a lot of code
}

//The problematic function
$('#modalEditLieu').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var lieu_id = button.data('lieu-id');
    $("#modalEditLieu .modal-body").html('').addClass('loading');
    $.get( "/lieux/" + lieu_id + "/edit", function( data ) {
        // Here I fill modal body with html send by ajax call
        $("#modalEditLieu .modal-body").html(data).removeClass('loading');

        // I tried to call functions again here
        init();
        initAutocomplete;
        fillInAddress();

        // I also tried to put it in 
        // $("#modalEditLieu .modal-body").html(data).promise().then(...) 
        // as suggested in some posts

    });
});

// I call all the functions in here
$('document').ready(function () {
    init();
    initAutocomplete;
    fillInAddress();
});

// I tried to call it in the ajaxComplete event as suggested but it does not work
$( 'document' ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    init();
    initAutocomplete;
    fillInAddress();
});
```

I understand that the functions called at first load are based on the first DOM and that they won't work on html dynamically loaded.

But I tried a lot of different ways and read a lot but I can't got it working...

Comment: By calling those same functions a second  time in the callback of your `.get` you are adding event listeners twice to everything outside of the modal. You should be adding those same event listeners that you do in those 3 functions to only the modal items or else with multiple event listeners on objects, you can have unintended behavior which may or may not be contributing to your problem.

Comment: **$( ‘document’ )** is not correct, as I remember. **$( document )** is

Comment: Thanks to both of you, @RyanWilson you're right, it works with chosen, at least. I can't got it working with tinyMCE but I keep trying.

Comment: And @muka-gergely You're right too, the ajaxComplete callback is now triggered !

Comment: @CharlieWebNancy You're welcome. Happy coding.